# Power BI - Is there a way to conditionally format a text column if it does NOT meet a criteria?

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

as the title states, is there a way to conditionally format a text column if it does NOT meet a criteria - In Power BI?

i.e: Format a column's font colour if it is NOT "x".

e.g:

I want to format the following data (using the letter column) and highlight a, b and c (as they are not equal to x)

```
ID | code | letter
------------------
1  | 123  | a
2  | 345  | b
3  | 567  | x
4  | 789  | c
------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create a measure to determine the desired highlight color for example, and use it, e.g. like this:

```
Measure = If(FIRSTNONBLANK('Table'[letter]; [letter]) = "x"; BLANK(); "#AABBCC")
```

[image]

[image]

See [Color formatting by field value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting#color-formatting-by-field-value):

> You can use a measure or a column that specifics a color, either using a text value or a hex code, to apply that color to the background of font color of a table or matrix visual. You can also create custom logic for a given field, and have that logic apply the desired color to the font or background.

You didn't mention what do you want to highlight and how. If the data will not be aggregated and show all rows in a table, you can calculate the highlighting color in conditional column in Power Query Editor, or computed column (DAX). If the highlighting rules will be applied on aggregated data, then you should use DAX measure.

If you want to highlight a cell, return the desired color. Otherwise return `null` in Power Query Editor, or `BLANK()` in DAX.

Comment: I am trying to just highlight the data that is NOT null/specific value. The table is a lot bigger, so I am trying to highlight all the non-x values to emphasise them.